# Listing files in directory using for each loop

Tags: j

I've read a few sample codes but I just don't understand how to use the foreach-like loop to iterate through the file collection. Here is how I get the list of files:

```
ls=:0 dir '*.*'
```

I can echo this out and it works fine. But what I need to do is process each file 1 at a time using some kind of loop. so something like:

```
ls=:0 dir '*.*'
foreach (file in ls) {
 do something(file)
 do something else.. so on
}
```

in the manuals a for each loop would look like this:

```
smoutput each i.10
```

Clearly that's no use, it prints 1 to 10, I don't know how to modify this to work with my directory listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `each` keyword is for a single-line loop. There is a [`for` loop](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/cfor.htm), which you can use inside a defined function (or verb).

Example:

```
myFunction =: 3 : 0
    ls =. 1 dir '*.*'
    for_file. ls do.
        doSomething ;file
        doSomethingElse ;file
    end.
)
```

The `for_.` variant is arguably the most useful. The name of your variable `file` goes right between the underscore and the period. The important thing to remember is that the for loop will give each item as it appears in the array, so if `ls` is an array of boxed strings, each `file` will show up as a single boxed string.

Comment: @ace007 That's got to go inside a function. You can't type that in the prompt directly. I'll edit. Also, note that `1 dir` will be easier to go through.

Comment: well it kinda works but after listing the first 2 files i get a "syntax error: myFunction | myFunction 0" am i calling the function correctly, I have also called it like myFunction''

Comment: You're calling it correctly. Notice I changed `0 dir` to `1 dir`. What are you doing inside your loop? What functions do you call there?

Comment: To achieve the result you wish, the natural way to do it in J would be to treat the list of file names as an array and work on the array/list directly. For example `myparsefn each fread each 1 dir '*.*'` would read the contents of each file in to a list of boxes and then parse the contents. This could be alternatively formulated as `myparsefn@fread each 1 dir '*.*'`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a list of this form:

```
ls =: 1 dir '*.*'
```

which is a list of files not a list of characters like `0 dir '*.*'`.

You can use `each` on this list, e.g.:

```
]ls =: 1 dir '*'
┌──────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────┐
│build_defs│build_jconsole│build_libj│build_tsdll│jconfig│
└──────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────┘

;# each ls  NB. number of characters for each filename
10 14 10 11 7
```